# How to hand off signing authority for a Safari extension

Tags: safari, code-signing, safari-extension

I'm developing an open-source extension for Safari. In the future, I might disengage and hand the project off to someone else. How would that work, given that the extension is signed using my personal Apple ID?

So let's say that I develop and sign version 1, and that Alice develops version 2. Would I need to sign Alice's version 2 (and her version 3, 4, etc.)? Is there a way for me to say "Alice is allowed to sign her own updates to this extension"?

Or maybe it's not that complicated: Does Safari even check to see if the new version is signed by the same Apple ID that signed the previous version?

Apple's [documentation for updating extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/UpdatingExtensions/UpdatingExtensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH12-SW1) just says that the update manifest needs to include a developer ID, but it says nothing about whether the new version's developer ID is compared against the old version's.

Answer (score 0):

If your project has a domain name, create an email address on that domain, and an Apple ID attached to it.
When you want to hand off the project, hand off the email/apple id altogether.

Or just create now a 2nd Apple Id and see if you can sign your extension with it.